# Infinite Loop in Hazelcast IMap for compute method

Tags: java, hazelcast

I try use `Set` interface as value for hazelcast `IMap` instance and when I run my test I found that test hung inside `ConcurrentMap#compute` method.

Why do I have infinite loop when I use `hazelcast` `IMap` in this code:

```
import com.hazelcast.config.Config;
import com.hazelcast.config.MapConfig;
import com.hazelcast.core.Hazelcast;
import com.hazelcast.core.IMap;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        IMap<String, HashSet<StringWrapper>> store = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(
                new Config().addMapConfig(new MapConfig("store"))
        ).getMap("store");
        store.compute("user", (k, value) -> {
            HashSet<StringWrapper> newValues = Objects.isNull(value) ? new HashSet<>() : new HashSet<>(value);
            newValues.add(new StringWrapper("user"));
            return newValues;
        });
        store.compute("user", (k, value) -> {
            HashSet<StringWrapper> newValues = Objects.isNull(value) ? new HashSet<>() : new HashSet<>(value);
            newValues.add(new StringWrapper("user"));
            return newValues;
        });

        System.out.println(store.keySet());
    }

    // Data class
    public static class StringWrapper implements Serializable {
        String value;

        public StringWrapper() {}

        public StringWrapper(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public String getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public void setValue(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if (this == o) return true;
            if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
            if (!super.equals(o)) return false;
            StringWrapper value = (StringWrapper) o;
            return Objects.equals(this.value, value.value);
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return Objects.hash(super.hashCode(), value);
        }
    }
}
```

Hazelcast: `3.9.3`
Java:`build 1.8.0_161-b12`
Operating system: `macOS High Sierra 10.13.3`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Alykoff I reproduced the issue based on above example & ArrayList version, which is reported as a github issue: https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/12557.

There are 2 seperate problems:

1 - When using HashSet, the problem is how Java deserialize the HashSet/ArrayList (collections) & how `compute` method works. Inside `compute` method (since Hazelcast complied with Java 6 & there is no `compute` method to override, default implementation from `ConcurrentMap` called ), this block causes the infinite loop:

```
// replace
if (replace(key, oldValue, newValue)) {
    // replaced as expected.
    return newValue;
}

// some other value replaced old value. try again.
oldValue = get(key);
```

this `replace` method calls IMap replace method. IMap checks if the current value equal to the user-supplied value. But because of a Java Serialization `optimization`, the check fails. Please check `HashSet.readObject` method. You'll see that when deserializing the HashSet, since element size is known, it creates the inner HashMap with a capacity:

```
// Set the capacity according to the size and load factor ensuring that
// the HashMap is at least 25% full but clamping to maximum capacity.
capacity = (int) Math.min(size * Math.min(1 / loadFactor, 4.0f),
        HashMap.MAXIMUM_CAPACITY);
```

But your `HashSet`, created without an initial capacity, has a default capacity of 16, while the deserialized one has the initial capacity of 1. This changes the serialization, index 51 contains the current capacity & it seems JDK re-calculate it based on size when deserializing the object to minimize the size.

Please see below example:

```
HazelcastInstance hz = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();

IMap<String, Collection<String>> store = instance.getMap("store");

Collection<String> val = new HashSet<>();
val.add("a");

store.put("a", val);

Collection<String> oldVal = store.get("a");

byte[] dataOld = ((HazelcastInstanceProxy) hz).getSerializationService().toBytes(oldVal);
byte[] dataNew = ((HazelcastInstanceProxy) hz).getSerializationService().toBytes(val);

System.out.println(Arrays.equals(dataNew, dataOld));
```

This code prints `false`. But if you create the `HashSet` with the initial size `1`, then both byte arrays are equal. And in your case, you won't get an infinite loop.

2 - When using `ArrayList`, or any other collection,  there's another problem which you pointed above. Due to how `compute` method implemented in `ConcurrentMap`, when you assign the old value to the `newValue` & add a new element, you actually modify the `oldValue` thus causing replace method fail. But when you change the code to `new ArrayList(value)`, now you're creating a `new ArrayList` & `value` collection is not modified. It's a best practice to wrap a collection before using it if you don't want to modify the original one. Same works for `HashSet` if you create with size `1` due to the first issue I explained.

So in your case, you should use

```
Collection<String> newValues = Objects.isNull(value) ? new HashSet<>(1) : new HashSet<>(value);
```

or

```
Collection<String> newValues = Objects.isNull(value) ? new ArrayList<>() : new ArrayList<>(value);
```

That `HashSet` case seems to be a JDK issue, rather than an optimization. I don't know any of these cases can be solved/fixed in Hazelcast, unless Hazalcast overrides the `HashXXX` collection serialization & overrides the `compute` method.